# CursorAdapter and scrolling: visibleItemCount becomes huge sporadically

Tags: android, listview

I have a `ListView` powered by a `CursorAdapter`. The `ListView` has `OnScrollListener` attached:

```
listView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        android.util.Log.e("===", "Scrolling: firstVisibleItem:" + firstVisibleItem + ", visibleItemCount:" + visibleItemCount + ", totalItemCount:" + totalItemCount);
        //some logic here
    }
});
```

As I scroll down and reach the bottom of the list new items are fetched from the network, added to the database and the cursor of `CursorAdapter` is updated to refresh the list:

```
adapter.changeCursor(newCursor); //the query for the cursor is always the same, it never changes
```

When I scroll up however and reach the middle or so of the list, sometimes `visibleItemCount` parameter is set to the value which is far greater than its usual value (40 vs usual 7-8). This is followed by a short lag and the list is instantly shifted back, closer to the bottom.

My CursorAdapter looks like this:

```
class MyCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    //...
    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, parent, false);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        populateView(view, cursor);
    }

    private void populateView(View view, Cursor cursor) {
        //...
        //this does not move the cursor, only reads from it
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

---

EDIT

The issue is actually not even related to CursorAdapter, I have replaced it with a regular BaseAdapter and the issue persists.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that root element of list view item had its `layout_height` equal to `wrap_content`. When there were many items in the view this would probably cause some performance issues inside the list view (or the adapter, I don't know). Changing `layout_height` to be exact value resolved the issue (and made list scrolling smoother):

```
layout_height="30dp"
```